# Problems in the connection process between moodle and rds in aws eks

Tags: amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws, moodle

I'm using terraform to distribute eks, rds, and kubernetes and try to run moodle. The image for moodle is using bitnami/moodle:latest.
Both eks and rds work on the same vpc, and the are generated very well. However, when I try to distribute moodle in kubernetes with rds, I experience problems with not accessing the database. What's the problem with connecting databases?

```
root@master:~/moodle_deploy# kubectl get pod
NAME                      READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
moodle-54f477b7f8-nh98h   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   15         70m
moodle-54f477b7f8-rhzzj   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   15         70m
```

```
root@master:~/moodle_deploy# kubectl logs moodle-54f477b7f8-rhzzj
moodle 06:33:12.43 
moodle 06:33:12.43 Welcome to the Bitnami moodle container
moodle 06:33:12.43 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/containers
moodle 06:33:12.43 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issuesmoodle 06:33:12.43 
moodle 06:33:12.44 INFO  ==> ** Starting Moodle setup **
realpath: /bitnami/apache/conf: No such file or directory
moodle 06:33:12.46 INFO  ==> Configuring Apache ServerTokens directive
moodle 06:33:12.49 INFO  ==> Configuring PHP options
moodle 06:33:12.49 INFO  ==> Setting PHP expose_php option
moodle 06:33:12.51 INFO  ==> Validating settings in MYSQL_CLIENT_* env vars
moodle 06:33:12.53 INFO  ==> Validating settings in POSTGRESQL_CLIENT_* env vars
moodle 06:33:12.69 INFO  ==> Ensuring Moodle directories exist
moodle 06:33:12.78 INFO  ==> Trying to connect to the database server
moodle 06:34:12.90 ERROR ==> Could not connect to the database
```

```
root@master:~/moodle_deploy# kubectl get pvc
NAME              STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
moodle-pv-claim   Bound    pvc-eefbb1d9-a6fd-4cf5-b044-159145798114   1Gi        RWO            gp2            59m
root@master:~/moodle_deploy# kubectl get pv
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                     STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
pvc-eefbb1d9-a6fd-4cf5-b044-159145798114   1Gi        RWO            Delete           Bound    default/moodle-pv-claim   gp2                     59m
```

These are the code that defined rds and kubernetes among the terraform files I distributed

```
//SECURITY GROUP
resource "aws_security_group" "secgrp-rds" {

  name        = "secgrp-rdis"
  description = "Allow MySQL Port"
  vpc_id          = module.vpc.vpc_id

  ingress {
    description = "Allowing Connection for mysql"
    from_port   = 3306
    to_port     = 3306
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {
    description = "Allowing Connection for SSH"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

}


resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "sub_ids" {
  name = "main"
  subnet_ids = module.vpc.private_subnets

  tags = {
    Name = "DB subnet group"
  }
}

//RDS INSTANCE
resource "aws_db_instance" "rds" {
  depends_on=[aws_security_group.secgrp-rds]
  engine               = "mysql"
  engine_version       = "5.7"
  instance_class       = "db.t2.micro"
  allocated_storage    = 20
  storage_type         = "gp2"
  name                 = "moodledb"
  identifier           = "moodledb"
  username             = "root"
  password             = "test12345"
  parameter_group_name = "default.mysql5.7"
  #publicly_accessible = true
  skip_final_snapshot = true
  apply_immediately   = true
  iam_database_authentication_enabled = true
  db_subnet_group_name = aws_db_subnet_group.sub_ids.id
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.secgrp-rds.id]

}
```

```
//CREATE DEPLOYMENT - provide rds environment variables
resource "kubernetes_deployment" "moodle" {
  depends_on = [aws_db_instance.rds]
  metadata {
    name = "moodle"
    labels = {
      App = "moodle"
    }
  }

  spec {
    replicas = 2
    selector {
      match_labels = {
        App = "moodle"
      }
    }
    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          App = "moodle"
        }
      }
      spec {
        container {
          image = "bitnami/moodle:latest"
          name  = "moodle"
          env{
            name = "MOODLE_DATABASE_TYPE"
            value = "mysqli"
          }


          env{
            name = "MOODLE_DATABASE_HOST"
            value = aws_db_instance.rds.endpoint
          }
          env{
            name = "MOODLE_DATABASE_USER"
            value = aws_db_instance.rds.username
          }
          env{
            name = "MOODLE_DATABASE_PASSWORD"
             value = aws_db_instance.rds.password
          }
          env{
            name = "MOODLE_DATABASE_NAME"
            value = aws_db_instance.rds.db_name
          }
          port {
            container_port = 8080
          }
          volume_mount {
            name = "moodle-ps"
            mount_path = "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/"
          }
          resources {
            limits= {
              cpu    = "0.5"
              memory = "512Mi"
            }
            requests= {
              cpu    = "250m"
              memory = "50Mi"
            }
          }
        }
      volume {
        name = "moodle-ps"
        persistent_volume_claim {
          claim_name = "moodle-pv-claim"
        }
      }
      }
    }

  }
}


resource "kubernetes_service" "moodle" {
  depends_on = [kubernetes_deployment.moodle]
  metadata {
    name = "moodle"
  }
  spec {
    port {
      port        = 80
      target_port = 8080
    }

    type = "LoadBalancer"
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_storage_class" "kubeSC" {
  metadata {
    name = "kubese"
  }
  storage_provisioner = "kubernetes.io/aws-ebs"
  reclaim_policy = "Retain"
  parameters = {
    type = "gp2"
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_persistent_volume_claim" "pvc" {
  depends_on=[kubernetes_storage_class.kubeSC]
  metadata {
    name = "moodle-pv-claim"
    labels = {
      "app" = "moodle"
    }
  }
  spec {
    access_modes = ["ReadWriteOnce"]
    resources {
      requests = {
        storage = "1Gi"
      }
    }
  }
}
```